# Automatic \ref from every variable to its definition

Tags: cross-referencing

Is it somehow possible to create a macro that links every variable from the text to the place where it was defined by using `\ref` or something similar?

Comment: what do you mean by Variable here? please provide a complete small (non working) example document and say what output you want.

Comment: I mean a variable like pressure p which is defined ar a certain place. The goal would be that every time I write p there is a hyperlink to its definition

Comment: if you have an equation `\begin{equation}p=whatever\label{pdef}\end{equation}` you can `\ref{pdef}` if you do not have that make a proper test document showing what you do have

Comment: A glossary can do that. you would for example use `\acrshort{P}` and it will hyperlink to the glossary where P is defined or the abbreviation is. The downside is that you must define every term . If want more on this, I can create a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a semi-automatic way to create the desired effect.

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709919/latex-equation-variables-defined-such-that-makeglossary-can-use-it)

### Explanation:

In this part:

```
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\mathgloss}[2]{
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1},description={#2}}
    \gls{#1} = #2
}
```

The user defined a new command to create both a new entry o the glossary and use that entry with `gls`

From this point, you could reference this exact equation and definition by calling `gls{e}`.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\mathgloss}[2]{
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1},description={#2}}
    \gls{#1} = #2
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    Consider the equation
    \begin{equation}
    e = m * c^2
    \end{equation}
    in which\\
    \mathgloss{e}{energy}\\
    \mathgloss{m}{mass}\\
    \mathgloss{c}{speed of light}
    
    \newpage
    \gls{e}
    
    \lipsum
    \gls{m}
    
    \lipsum 
    \gls{m} 
    
    \lipsum
    \gls{c}
    
    \printglossaries
\end{document}
```